# creating draggable pin annotation but should stop it from dragging on a button

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mapkit, draggable

I have created draggable pin annotation and it is working perfectly fine, the problem is i don't want to drag and drop pins on a particular button click and even don't want to reload map as i am having overlays on it, i have used `DDAnnotation` class for draggable pins

```
DDAnnotation *annotation = [[DDAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:theCoordinate addressDictionary:nil];
annotation.title = @"Testing";
annotation.subtitle = @"Drag and Drop Pin";

[self.detailMapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

Thanks

Any help would be really appreciable!

Answer (score 1):

Please set   [annotation setDraggable:NO];